# In chat, what is the difference between "hide posts" and "ignore this user"

Tags: support, chat, ignored-users

They seem to do the same thing..

- They **both** make the avatar of the user <sub><sup>small</sup></sub>
- They **both** hide all of the posts of the user that you are "hide"ing or "ignore"ing
- They **both** can be undone if you click ***either*** "show posts" *or* "don't ignore this user"

Is there any real difference?

And if there isn't any difference, can we remove one of them so we have just **one** term for hiding (or ignoring) a user in chat?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Hide posts" just hides them for that 'session' (i.e. you refresh and they are back!)

"Ignore this user everywhere" is persistent across rooms / sessions.

---

On the opposite side of things, the "show posts" also works for the session. You can "show posts" to see what the user is saying at that point in time, but when you refresh they are once again ignored.

Comment: Yes, but "show posts" seems to **undo** the ignoring!

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: Ahhh I see ^_^.

Comment: @AnnaLear, you know how often I freaking do that!??!?! you would think I would learn.... ohh well. :)