# How to unhide chat messages by hidden user

Tags: support, chat, ignored-users

I hid messages from the chat bot [sintel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-198/sintel) by clicking *hide posts*, mostly as a test to see what it does.

[image]

However, hiding posts also hid the profile picture associated with them, which is where the option originally was. Try as I might, I can't find a way to unhide the hidden posts..

What am I missing?

Comment: You mean you clicked "ignore this user"? Or did something else to hide the messages?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added a screenshot

Answer (score 3):

When choosing "hide posts" or "ignore this user", his/her avatar is not totally gone, just shrinking to a smaller size. You have to hover the users and you will see it:

> [image]

Clicking the small avatar will give you the card again where you can choose "show posts".

Comment: But the said user isn't in that list, small or normal.. (it's a bot, if that matters)

Comment: @gandalf3 so it means he's not in the room. If you leave the room and join again, I believe you will see past posts from that user again i.e. the chat should not "remember" the hide posts action.

Comment: @gandalf3 being a bot does not matter, it's still a totally valid chat profile.

Comment: I ended up just refreshing the page, and that worked (and is probably faster than leaving and rejoining). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156161/238438), I just refreshed the page and the hidden posts came back.